# Problem in number of view time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

As i have posted a question it get two up votes  it means minimum two viewer viewed 
my question but as i see in view time it shows only 1. There may be some problem.

[image]

Comment: Did you refresh the page (pressed the F5 button)? Also, it's possible that not everything is updated at exactly the same time. If you see this consistently after refreshing then it's a bug, but at the moment I see 3 views (and 3 upvotes)

Comment: yes i refreshed at that time and now its updated ... it showing me 10 now so it may take a time to update.. i am clear now

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of questions of this kind on meta.SO

The answer is almost always server-side caching - give it time, and it will update.

In this case, that is the answer.

Comment: I think that the upvotes, reputation & notifications get updated via javascript without refreshing the page, but most elements (including page visits) only get updated after refreshing the page. So it may not have anything to do with caching.